# How can I rotate a text and put it into a Bootstrap column?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, transform, rotatetransform

I'm searching all day on stackoverflow for ways to rotate my text, but when I add bootstrap column stuff it just breaks...

I'm writing a page that have 2 colums for title and 10 columns for the content.

The title text should be a vertical text all along the box height and the content should be anything like text or img.

Here is the html/css that I've wrote:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row" style="height: 350px;">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <div class="vertical-text">
            <h3>some text</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
        <div class="some-img"></div>
        <div class="some-text">
            <p>blablablabla</p>
            <p>blablablabla</p>
            <p>blablablabla</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.vertical-text {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    background: green;
}

.row { padding: 15px; }
```

Jsfiddle with the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/cxhmssam/1/

Comment: I don't understand what your issue is. Your fiddle shows the text rotated. If you're looking in IE9 then it requires a vender prefix, along with Safari 8: http://caniuse.com/#search=transform

Answer (score 0):

Your jsfiddle shows the "some text" vertically for me.

As suggested by @Shane, you might want to try `-ms-transform`.

quoting [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp):

```
div {
    -ms-transform: rotate(7deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(7deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(7deg);
}
```